# How to get the list of plugins and dependencies added in the pom.xml file in last one month in git

Tags: bash, git

I have requirement where I want to get the report of newly added plugins or dependencies in the `pom.xml` file for last one month. The `pom.xml` file is in git. I want the artifactId and version number of the plugin

I have done this way

```
git whatchanged --since=$startDate  --until=$endDate -p -- pom.xml | grep '^[+]' | sed -n "/<plugin>/,/<\/plugin>/p" | awk -v FS="(<artifactId>|</artifactId>|<version></version>)" '{print $2}' >> $BaseDir/plugins.xls
```

but it prints plugin name then the version on next line like below:

```
PluginName1
4.5.7
PluginName2
7.4.5
PluginName3
8.3.6
```

I want like this:

```
PluginName1 4.5.7
PluginName2 7.4.5
PluginName3 8.3.6
```

Or is there any other way I can do this instead of awk?

Comment: As you are mention pom.xml file, I'm thinking you use `Maven`. Maybe worth to see dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree` and it's output parameters or mix with grep/awk/etc. See more details https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html